# Bash: set associative array from variable

Tags: bash

I am getting some data returned from a command line tool and would like to fill an associative array with the data. I can alter the format of the data returned, but how must it be to the associative array?

```
content="[key1]=val1 [key2]=val2" # How should this be formatted?

declare -A hashTable
hashTable=($content) # How to set it?

declare -p hashTable
```

Comment: @Adamarla: Could you provide how the command-line tool actually returns the output? It is not easy to understand from a variable

Comment: Can the value take spaces? Unless you show some actual values, it will tough to parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you master `content` and understand well bash parsing, for example not coming from exernal input

```
eval "hashTable=($content)"
```

otherwise you have to parse it to ensure no injection (as eval reinterpret data as code, bash expression), imagine content contains `echo` given as example

```
content=');echo hey;x=('
```

maybe easier to split the `content` :

```
hashTable=()
tmp=$content
while [[ $tmp = *\[* ]] && tmp=${tmp#*\[} || tmp=; [[ $tmp ]]; do
    cur=${tmp%%\[*};
    val=${cur#*\]=};
    hashTable[${cur%%\]=*}]=${val%${val##*[![:space:]]}}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to format the output of the first command like this

```
key1=value1 key2=value2
```

without spaces in value2 and without '=', then you can try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
content="key1=val1 key2=val2"   

declare -A hashTable

for pair in $content ; do 
  key=${pair%=*}        # take the part of the string $pair before '='
  value=${pair/#*=/}    # take the part of the string $pair after '='
  hashTable[$key]=$value
done

for K in "${!hashTable[@]}";  do echo hashTable\[$K\]=${hashTable[$K]}; done
```

Comment: Iterating over unquoted `$content` is not going to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (which requires `bash` 4.4 or later) is to have your command return a string alternating keys and values, each terminated by a null character. You can then use `readArray` to parse this into an indexed array, then build your associative array from that.

```
$ readArray -t -d '' foo < <(printf 'key1\0value1\0key2\0value2\0')
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="key1" [1]="value1" [2]="key2" [3]="value2")
$ for ((i=0; i < ${#foo[@]}; i+=2)); do
>  hashTable[${foo[i]}]=${foo[i+1]}
> done
$ declare -p hashTable
declare -A hashTable=([key2]="value2" [key1]="value1" )
```

`bash` 4.4 is required for the `-d` option to `readArray`. In earlier 4.x releases, you can use a string with embedded newlines, but that precludes your keys or values from themselves containing newlines.

(Note that in the assignments to `hashTable`, you can safely leave both `${foo[i]}` and `${foo[i+1]}` unquoted, as neither the key nor the value will undergo word splitting or pathname expansion. It doesn't hurt to quote them if you wish, though.)